# Cannot Insert Data into MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

There are two blocks of data.

Block 1:

"Completed the main phase of development of version 9.8, release is on testing and        preparation, but for now we suggest you read the information about what awaits you with a new release. In this release, you are invited to a new system, through which your visitors can share interesting information on your site to other people, as well as in social networks, the new quick lock spammers on the site, the new template tags, new options for custom display of news and much more but everything in detail."

Block 2:

"I'm not afraid (I'm not afraid)
To take a stand (to take a stand)
Everybody (everybody)
Come take my hand (come take my hand)
We'll walk this road together, through the storm
Whatever weather, cold or warm
Just letting you know that, you're not alone
Holla if you feel like you've been down the same road (same road)"

I can INSERT the first block of data into the MySQL table easily, but i cannot INSERT the second block.

Why ???

Comment: because you aren't formatting your SQL properly

Comment: You should provide at least your code.

Comment: no need to provide any code, the problem is as clear as a fresh water.

Comment: the commas http://theoatmeal.com/comics/apostrophe _just read the title_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for escaping the text in `INSERT` query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) for your inserts.

```
// here goes connection code from the link above

$data = "I'm not afraid (I'm not afraid) To take a stand (to take a stand) Everybody (everybody) Come take my hand (come take my hand) We'll walk this road together, through the storm Whatever weather, cold or warm Just letting you know that, you're not alone Holla if you feel like you've been down the same road (same road)";
$stm = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table SET field=?");
$stm->execute(array($data));
```

Comment: Surely PDO Is not the only valid API in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As i can see your first block doesn't have single quotes and the second one have single quotes and double quotes so i think your solution will be solved by escaping quotes try and tell me the result :)

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, i think that the characters '  may broke your query, try to insert a \ before the ' in this fashion and try to re-execute the query:

```
\'
```